# Force base_link to stay at 0

Tags: contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My robot has a disc with a radius of 1.25m in contact with the ground. Apparently this is not handled very well by the simulator and the robots drifts slowly with time. How to force base_link to stay at zero position? Is there a way to define as static a link only and not the whole robot?

I am using URDF and world frame doesn't seem to be usable there as parent frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8897/force-base_link-to-stay-at-0/) by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Following chapulina's answer, my URDF joint looks like this:

```
<link name="world"/>
<joint name="joint_base_world" type="fixed">
  <child link="base_link" />
  <parent link="world" />
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
</joint>
```

An explicit definition of the world frame is necessary when using URDF's. This joint stabilizes my robot and makes it fixed at zero position.

---

Originally posted by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) with karma: 94 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can create a joint between `base_link` and the world, [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/74a580447dd670bc78f9f9e476a6d5d3ffd69563/fire_hose_long/model.sdf?at=default#cl-5)'s an example.

Assuming your disk is rotating about its Z axis, it would look something like this:

```
<joint name="joint_base_world" type="revolute">
  <child>base_link</child>
  <parent>world</parent>
  <axis>
    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on 2015-06-17**:
Thanks, I edited my question to precise that I am using URDFs, the world frame doesn't seem to be recognized there.